# How can I start x11vnc headless?

Tags: systemd-startup

Currently, I am starting x11vnc on my Pi 400 (stock Raspbian) after it boots up (with no display attached) via ssh with command `x11vnc -forever -display :0`

How can I do it with systemd? I am trying this file:

```
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -forever -display :0 > /home/pi/x11vnc.log

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

but that does not seem to work? Any ideas why? I am quite new to systemd.

Comment: Why not just use the provided VNC server and the normal desktop?  Just set the default resolution and start up mode to GUI (needing sign-on) in raspi-config and then connect to the VNC server from your client...

Comment: Welcome.  Please edit in the output from `systemctl status whateverthatserviceiscalled`.

Comment: goldilocks : with the accepted answer below, it works already.

Andyroo : If I understand it correctly, it would start a new X dispaly. I want to see the same display as I use through VNC once and when I turn on my projector. But I did not specifu that in the question.

Comment: No wonder I was baffled :-) No problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc
After=graphical.target

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -forever

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Don't forget to enable the service:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable yourx11vnc.service
```

The logged messages you will find in the journal with `journalctl -b -e`.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. Especially for the journal bit. Though I get a message seemingly written in 2006 about using -ncache. But it warks flawlessly.